# How to select the element  in javascript?

Tags: javascript

the dom as the following:

```
<li class="category51">
<a class="drop" href="#">Data</a>
<div class="dropdown_2column align_left ">
<div class="col_1">
<ul>
<li class="level1">
<a href="#">
<span class="level1">Solutions1</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="level1">
<a href="#">
<span class="level1">Solutions</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

i want to get  `Solutions1 and Solutions` a lable. how should i do?i using:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("category51").document.getElementsByTagName(ul).document.getElementsByTagName(li).document.getElementsByTagName(a).
```

what i want to achieve:

i want to disable  the link by javascript.so i must bind an event to the a lable, now, i don't know how to locate it.

Comment: I think your post doesn't contain enough context to explain the code sections, please expand your question somewhat and describe what you want to achieve

Comment: i want to disable the link by javascript.so i must bind an event to the a lable, now, i don't know how to locate it.

Comment: @downa1234 What do you want to locate?

Comment: tha a link label of Solutions1 and Solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Document.querySelecorAll`.

```
var eles = document.querySelectorAll('li.level1 a'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < eles.length, i++) {
  eles[i].onclick = function() {
    //...
  };
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i want to select, tha a link label outside of text Solutions1 and Solutions. the <a>. thank you

Comment: @downa1234 Could you put your expected result in your question?

Comment: eg: if in jquery, it maybe $("li.level1 a"). how to get the same effect in javascript

Comment: i want to disable the a link, i used your code, but the a link still can click. my code:var eles = document.querySelectorAll('li.category51 li.level1 a'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < eles.length, i++) {
  eles[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.stop();
  };
}

Comment: @downa1234 Change `e.stop()` to `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: many thanks, it's ok. if i want to the code do ok under IE7,how should i replace Document.querySelecorAll?

Comment: i want to change finger pointer to cursor when the mouse hover on it.which code should i add?